# Get-ChildItem execute git status

Tags: git, powershell-2.0

I would like to be able to use Windows PowerShell command

```
Get-ChildItem -include .git  -Force -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Attributes -match "Hidden"}
```

and execute `git status` for every "record" found and output it to a text file.

This way I will be able to have a report of my unsync changes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? this seems to be a bit of the long way around

Comment: Have a look at `Pit` - https://github.com/manojlds/pit . It tries to solve something like what you are doing. Care to raise a issue for your exact use case and we can do that?

Comment: What do you think about this? Get-ChildItem -include .git  -Force -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Attributes -match "Hidden"} | foreach-object {$a=Get-Location; cd $_.parent.fullname; Get-Location; git status; cd $a;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I will set an alias in my profile for this command.

```
Get-ChildItem -include .git -Force -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Attributes -match "Hidden"} | foreach-object {$a=Get-Location; cd $_.parent.fullname; Get-Location; git status; cd $a;}
```